# C struct member within struct to function

Tags: c, function, struct, arguments, member

Let say we have those 2 struct :

```
struct date
{
   int date;
   int month;
   int year; 
};

struct Employee
   {
   char ename[20];
   int ssn;
   float salary;
   struct date dateOfBirth;
};
```

If i want to use a member of a struct to send it to a function, let say we have this function :

```
void printBirth(date d){
   printf("Born in %d - %d - %d ", d->date, d->month, d->year);
}
```

My understanding is if im defining an Employee and i want to print his date of birth, i would do :

```
Employee emp;
emp = (Employee)(malloc(sizeof(Employee));

emp->dateOfBirth->date = 2;  // Normally, im asking the user the value
emp->dateOfBirth->month = 2; // Normally, im asking the user the value
emp->dateOfBirth->year = 1948; // Normally, im asking the user the value


//call to my function :
printBirth(emp->dateOfBirth);
```

But when i do this, i get an error : 
warning: passing argument 1 of 'functionName'(in our case it would be printBirth) from incompatible pointer type.

I know that it would be easier if the function would work with a pointer of struct date but i dont have that option. The function must receive a struct date as parameters.

So i wanted to know how am i suppose to pass a struct defined within a struct to a function.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `Employee *emp;
emp = (Employee *)(malloc(sizeof(Employee));

emp->dateOfBirth.date = 2;`...

Comment: Depending on the compiler, you might need to either prefix Employee and date with struct like `struct Employee` or use typedefs like `typedef struct {...} Employee`.

Comment: or `Employee emp = { "", 0, 0.0f, {2,2,1948}};`..`printBirth(emp.dateOfBirth);`

Comment: The 1st answer of BLUEPIXY help me a lot to figure it out. Everything works now. Thanks a lot.

I dont have the options the marked this question Answered, i dont know how to do it. Usally, i saw a big check mark that i can put in green..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
   int date;
   int month;
   int year; 
} date;

typedef struct
{
   char ename[20];
   int ssn;
   float salary;
   date dateOfBirth;
} Employee;

void printBirth(date *d){
   printf("Born in %d - %d - %d \n", d->date, d->month, d->year);
}

int main () 
{
    Employee emp;

    emp.dateOfBirth.date = 2;  
    emp.dateOfBirth.month = 2;
    emp.dateOfBirth.year = 1948;

    printBirth(&emp.dateOfBirth);
}
```

I want to advice to use `typedef` when youre working with structures. if you're using `typedef` you no longer need to write `struct` all over the place by useing typedef code is more cleaner since it provides a smidgen more abstraction